# SharePoint Picture library - Show Title, Modified in Tiles view instead of Filename, Modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, office-365-developer

I am using SharePoint Online Picture library, where images are being displayed in tiles view.

I noticed that thumbnail image contains Filename + Modified date on the tiles as per below screenshot.

Is it possible to show Title of the image + Modified date on the Tiles ?

I tried formatting the JSON for entire row in Modern view, able to get the Title of the column, but the tile becomes non-clickable.

Based on below screenshot, title MyImage should be shown in place of 20170915_095235.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For modern experience in SharePoint Online, I assume using JSON formatting will be a good way to change the text displayed on the thumbnail. Per my test, after applying still I can click on the thumbnail and open it in a new tab.

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideColumnHeader": "true",
  "hideSelection": false,
  "tileProps": {
    "hideSelection": false,
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "attributes": {
            "class": "ms-bgColor-neutralLighter ms-bgColor-neutralSecondaryAlt--hover ms-fontColor-white--hover"
          },
          "style": {
            "display": "flex",
            "flex-wrap": "wrap",
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "100%",
            "margin-right": "10px",
            "margin-top": "10px",
            "box-shadow": "2px 2px 4px darkgrey"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "margin": "auto",
                "text-align": "center"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "elmType": "img",
                  "attributes": {
                    "src": "@thumbnail.large"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "margin": "auto",
                    "font-size": "16px",
                    "text-align": "center"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$Title]"
                },
                {
                  "elmType": "div",
                  "style": {
                    "font-size": "13px",
                    "font-style": "oblique",
                    "text-align": "left",
                    "padding": "5px"
                  },
                  "txtContent": "[$Modified]"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I edited a bit from the json code from a blog and worked.
Reference:https://devscopeninjas.azurewebsites.net/2019/12/19/tiles-view-formatting-thumbnail-along-with-description-and-keywords/

[image]

**Update**

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "tileProps": {
    "formatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "margin": "auto",
            "text-align": "center"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "img",
              "attributes": {
                "src": "=if(indexOf([$FileLeafRef],'.')>0,'@thumbnail.medium','https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric-cdn-prod_20200921.001//office-ui-fabric-react-assets/foldericons/lg-bg.svg')"
              }
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "margin": "auto",
                "font-size": "16px",
                "text-align": "center"
              },
              "txtContent": "[$Title]"
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "style": {
                "font-size": "13px",
                "font-style": "oblique",
                "text-align": "left",
                "padding": "5px"
              },
              "txtContent": "[$Modified]"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jerry_MSFT, Is it possible to get the same folder image, as we get in modern view. Folder image at the parent level and at child level file image ?

Comment: @KoolRaj，I updated with a new json, however it is faraway from a perfect one. It simple check if the new item has an extension, if not I will assume it to be a folder. Have a try with it and would be better to get some experts on JSON formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to have same folder preview at parent level, as we have in modern view like below ?[image]